# How to format a HTML table so that I can insert extra cells in a cell that has a rowspan=2 attribute?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I am trying to create a table that I can insert webparts into that looks like this.

[image]

The current code I have is

```
<table border="1">
 <tr>
   <td>Clk Map</td>
   <td rowspan="2">
   ///extra in here
   </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
   <td>ImgeCar</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

and when I tried this it just totally broke.

```
<table border="1">
 <tr>
  <td>Clk Map</td>
  <td rowspan="2">
   <tr>
    <td>a</td>
    <td>b</td>
    <td>c</td>
   </tr>
  </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>ImgeCar</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Well, for one, you've just got a row `<TR>` starting straight in a cell `<TD>`  Do you want this?  http://jsfiddle.net/gdz2F/

Comment: Don't insert extra cells ... insert `<div>` or `<span>` tags

Comment: This can be recreated without the use of tables:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15164327/equally-distributing-height-with-css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a quick fix for your problem - see it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/3ZmvS/286/) (you are missing a **table** element)

```
<table border="1">
 <tr>
  <td>Clk Map</td>
  <td rowspan="2">
   **<table>**
    <tr>
     <td>a</td>
     <td>b</td>
     <td>c</td>
    </tr>
   **</table>**
  </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>ImgeCar</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

On the second thought, [**this**](http://jsfiddle.net/3ZmvS/287/) would be closer to what your asked for in the mock-up:

```
<table border="1">
 <tr>
  <td>Clk Map</td>
  <td rowspan="2">
   **<table>**
    <tr>
     <td>a</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>b</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>c</td>
    </tr>
   **</table>**
  </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>ImgeCar</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

However, consider learning about css (especially float in this example) which is the right way to solve your problem. It will help you immensely in the long run.

Comment: The table element is what was missing. But the final code was a little different. Like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/3ZmvS/286/)

Answer (score 1):

Like Mituw16 mentioned... for a data presentation like you're proposing... something without a normalized tabular structure, you should be doing this without tables.

Something along the lines of housing your click map and image carousel in a DIV or similar container to the left... float it left, then have the news items in a container on the right, floated left.  This will allow the right side content to "grow" without having to deal with the rowspan accounting on successive additions.

```
<div id="holdme">
    <div id="lcol">
        <div id="clickmap">CLICK MAP</div>
        <div id="carousel">CAROUSEL</div>
    </div>
    <div id="rcol">
        <div class="newsitem">News Item</div>
      ...
        <div class="newsitem">News Item</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

See the following http://jsfiddle.net/J9543/

Comment: I would usually, but im modifying someone elses coded and this is how they would like me to do it.

Comment: @Mufasatheking Juggling colspans is a maintenance nightmare waiting to happen.