# 2 DIVs (or more) in 1 TD (table), how to fill TD with 2 DIVs, the image below :

Tags: html, position, html-table

I want to set two divs or more divs in a td, how can achieve to fill whole td by 2 divs without spaces, i am using IE8.

Thanks with regards.

I want this :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/cZSLS.png

Instead of this, what i have actually (real case):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kp142.png

Comment: Maybe this is helpful here: [Equally distributing height with CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15164327/1456376)

Comment: Hi, i am using IE 8, your suggestion is not working in ie8.

Answer (score 1):

try: `width: 100%; display: inline-block;`

edit: I just read that if this doesn't work you might have forgotten `<!DOCTYPE html>` at the start of the document

Comment: Hi, width: 100%; display: inline-block : In wich element i define (div or td) ?

Answer (score 0):

You can create as below

```
 <body >
   <table border=1 width=100>
     <tr>
      <td>
             <div style="border:solid red 2px;">
              corpus form
            </div>
            <div style="border:solid green 2px;
                 border-style: none solid  solid solid;">
               corpus form
            </div>
       </td>
      </tr>
   </table>
  </body>
```

Comment: What is the issue you are getting in applying above code

Comment: Please see the question again i came to re-edited with my real example.